# On the existence of topological spaces $X$ such that $C_0(X) \neq \overline{C_c(X)}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be any topologoical space (not necessarily **Hausdorff**), and let $C_b(X)$ be the set of bounded continuous functions equipped with the supremum norm.

We say a subset of $X$ is compact if every open cover has a finite subcover. We say a function $f$ vanishes at infinity if for any $\epsilon＞0,$ the set
$\{x\in X|\ |f(x)|\leq \epsilon\} $ is compact.

Let $C_0(X)$ be the continuous functions which vanish at infinity, and let $C_c(X)$ be the continuous functions which have compact support.

Is there a
topological space  $X$ such that
$$C_0(X)\neq \overline{C_c(X)}.$$

I have known this is impossible if $X$
is Hausdorff.

Comment: Why is the sup norm of a continuous function finite?

Comment: We may just consider bounded continuous functions, the lateter two spaces satisfy such condition.

Comment: 1. What does it mean that a function vanishes at infinity? 2. By a compact set (subset of $X$) do you mean a set such that every open cover has a finite subcover, or must it also be Hausdorff?

Comment: @Adayah Sorry,  I have given the definitions.

Answer (score 4):

No, the property $C_0(X) = \overline{C_c(X)}$ holds for every topological space $X$.

**Proof.**
$(\subseteq)$ Assume $f \in C_0(X)$ and take $\varepsilon > 0$.  Define $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ so that

- $\varphi$ maps $[0, \varepsilon]$ to $0$;
- $\varphi$ maps $[\varepsilon, 2\varepsilon]$ onto $[0, 2\varepsilon]$ linearly;
- $\varphi$ acts as identity on $[2\varepsilon, \infty)$;
- $\varphi$ is odd.

We claim that $\varphi \circ f$ is a function in $C_c(X)$ such that $\| f - \varphi \circ f \|_{\infty} \leqslant \varepsilon$. The second condition is trivial and for the first note that

$$\operatorname{\text{supp}}(\varphi \circ f) = \overline{\{ x \in X : (\varphi \circ f)(x) \neq 0 \}} \subseteq \{ x \in X : |f(x)| \geqslant \varepsilon \}.$$

Therefore $\operatorname{\text{supp}}(\varphi \circ f)$ is compact as a closed subset of a compact set (this property does not require $X$ to be Hausdorff), and so $\varphi \circ f \in C_c(X)$.

$(\supseteq)$ Assume $f \in \overline{C_c(X)}$ and take $\varepsilon > 0$. Pick $g \in C_c(X)$ such that $\| f - g \|_{\infty} < \varepsilon$. Then

$$\{ x \in X : |f(x)| \geqslant \varepsilon \} \subseteq \operatorname{\text{supp}} g,$$

so the set on the left is compact as a closed subset of a compact set. Hence $f \in C_0(X)$.

Comment: Thanks, but I think there is a typo, it should be $ ||f-\varphi\circ f||_{\infty}\leq 2\epsilon$.

Comment: @qinxs For which $y \in \mathbb{R}$ do you think that $|y - \varphi(y)| > \varepsilon$?

Comment: There is no problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: I beg to differ. If there exists $f\in C_0(X)$ then $X=\cup_{n\in\Bbb N}\{x: |f(x)|\le n\}$ so $X$ is a countable union of compact subsets (a.k.a. $\sigma$-compact}. So if $X$ is not $\sigma$-compact then $C_0(X)=\emptyset.$ For example if $X$ is uncountable and discrete then $C_0(X)$ is empty but $C_c(X)$ is not empty. However, this is according to the proposer's def'n of $C_0(X)$ (as of Aug. 16/2022 at 21:00 EDT) and this def'n does not look right to me.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You're right. But the definition in the OP seems so obviously wrong that I silently assumed it must be $\{ x \in X : |f(x)| \geqslant \varepsilon \}$.

Comment: OK...........................